# how to track in gridview whether filter is applied or not in extjs?

Tags: gridview, extjs, extjs3

My task is to put an image on the extjs grid column header whenever filter is applied in that column. When filter is cleared remove the image from the grid column header.

How to achieve this in extjs 3?

Comment: I answered a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209855/adding-filter-icon-in-extjs-grid-column-once-after-filter-is-applied/39263654#39263654

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS 3.4 when filter is active on a column `.ux-filtered-column` class is added to the header cell. Easiest way is to add custom style for this class.

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a reference to the grid it is used by. Hence, you could use `this.grid.store.isFiltered()` to check whether store is filtered.

You probably want to perform such check in the listener function bind to `datachanged` event of grid's store:

```
initComponent: function() {
     ...
     this.grid.store.on('datachanged', this.yourDesiredFunction, this);
     ...
}

yourDesiredFunction: function(store) {
    if (store.isFiltered()) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do i for which columns filters have been applied?

Comment: This is answer is not relevant to the question. @JackAss the right way to get hold of column is `this.grid.filters.getMenuFilter()`. I know its true late but I am write because if someone use in future they use correctly.

Answer (score 0):

custom style for class .ux-filtered-column works good.
However **.ux-filtered-column** is not getting added to the header cell if it is **grouped header grid**.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.The .ux-filtered-column was not effective.But in that I added background image,which worked finally.